# How can my powershell script contribute to the Timeline screen on an Azure DevOps build?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

Notice the `PowerShell Script` step below:

[image: Timeline]

This is my script. I want it to add more steps to this Timeline screen. I looked at https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md and thought that something like `##vso[task.setprogress value=75;]Upload Log` would do it, but outputting this has no effect.

So, how can this be done?

Comment: Look at the `logdetail` section of that documentation. That's what you want.

Comment: Yup, you are right. Please arrange it as an answer so I could credit you.